# Weird font rendering in FF

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, rendering

I have this weird font rendering bug in FF 38.05 on Windows 8, font is loaded from TypeKit, I could not find anything on that in FF issue tracker.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am on Ubuntu and I don't have this problem, neither any of Windows machines on BrowserStack. If this is just system or hardware problem, then how to solve it?

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro/issues/64